# Fields saved on Firestore as string but the "where" clausule needs a string

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore DB with hundreds (~700) of documents like this:

```
{
  name: string
  email: string
  coins: string
  ...
}
```

The problem is the "coins" are stored as strings instead of numbers.

My query is:

```
  ...
  .where('coins', '>=', 0)
  .where('coins', '<=', 30)
  .get();
```

This query fetches `10`, `20`, `100`, `200`, `299999`, etc, because it's considering only the first character.

The expected result should have only `10`, `15`, `20`, and `29`.

Do you have any suggestions about how to make this work on the `where()` clause?

In the worst case, how to convert all "coins" types from `string` to `number` at once?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot make the query work with the data you have now.  The coins field type needs to be a number if you want it sorted numerically.  You will have to read each document individually, modify the data in memory, then write it back out.  There is no bulk update.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson
I'll do this temporarily then I'll create something to modify the field type.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @DougStevenson :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this as a community wiki. As mentioned by @DougStevenson above in the comments.

You cannot make the query work with the data you have now. The coins field type needs to be a number if you want it sorted numerically. You will have to read each document individually, modify the data in memory, then write it back out. There is no bulk update.